# Is Facebook ghost banning event invites and are there any other restrictions when inviting friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I know YouTube has a feature of "ghost banning" - owner of the channel bans the user, they can still submit comments but they are visible only to them.

[image]

I'm wondering if FB events are doing the same?

Before I start inviting everyone on my contact list, I would like to know if I'll be "shadow banned"...

That is - for me it will appear as if the invite was sent but in reality no notification, no nothing.

---

I can imagine that such behaviour would be problematic and could often lead to confusion:

> Q: Have you seen my invite?
>
> A: NOPE

---

Slightly related question - is there a limit on number of friends I can invite per day / per 24 hour period?

Answer (score 2):

Unless these people have blocked you, they will receive the invite. That is the only condition I can think of where you could send an invite but they never receive it.

To answer your other question you may send up to **[500 invites per event](https://www.facebook.com/help/202545109787461)**. If you wish to add more people (and it is a private event) you can add a co-host to the event who can send another 500 invites or you can edit your events privacy setting to allow your friends to invite more people.